# UIImage from CIImage - Data length is zero?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-image

I'm using an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` along with its delegate method to manipulate video frames. In the delegate method, I am using the `sampleBuffer` to create a `CIImage`, and from here I crop the `CIImage`, convert it to a `UIImage` and display it. Unfortunately, I need to determine the file-size of this new `UIImage`, but it's returning `0`. The code works, the image is cropped beautifully, everything. I just don't see why it has no data!

Why might this be? Relevant code follows:

```
//In delegate method, given sampleBuffer...
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer 
                                                  options:(NSDictionary *)attachments];

...


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    CGRect rect = [self drawFaceBoxesForFeatures:features forVideoBox:clap
                                                 orientation:curDeviceOrientation];

    CIImage *cropped = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:rect];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:cropped];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    NSLog(@"Image size is %d", data.length); //returns 0???

    [imageView setImage:image];

    [image release];
});
```

Comment: Just a NB - `data.length` returns an unsigned int, so your `NSLog` statement should look like this instead: `NSLog(@"Image size is %u", data.length)`

Comment: This is true - though it has no effect on the output. I'm trying to sift through Apple's docs, just because I know that CoreImage isn't actually an image, just a data representation. But it is beyond me at this point why it wouldn't have data when converted..

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I'm stumped on your actual problem - assuming that when you breakpoint after calling `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` your `NSData` object actually has data in it.

Comment: Well with further testing no - no data exists in the `NSData` object. But I am getting a correctly cropped image displayed every frame in my `UIImageView`, which confuses the heck outta me. It has no problem converting to `UIImage` for display yet has no data.

Comment: Don't you have to use CGImage's for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` not CIImage? But even if CIImage works wouldn't the code be: `NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.CIImage, 1);`

Comment: This may help you: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1128-getting-data-from-an-uiimage.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem, but with simple filtered images.

I stumbled upon [this](http://picopikopon.blogspot.de/2011/11/how-to-convert-ciimage-to-jpeg.html) and it solved the issue. After this, I was able to save my image.

```
CGSize size = self.originalImage.size;
CGRect rect;
rect.origin = CGPointZero;
rect.size   = size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[[UIImage imageWithCIImage:self.filteredImage] drawInRect:rect];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData * jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

But I only needed this two lines in the "ImageContext"